# File unable to upload through struts2

Tags: java, struts2

I have created a simple form where user select's a file and uploads it using a button. I have used struts 2 .I select file format like jpg,txt to upload and it creates a tmp file.
Whenever I upload the file following error is shown on eclipse-

```
Mar 16, 2018 4:52:00 PM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger info
INFO: Removing file uploadFile \EmployeeDocuments\upload__5c8c539e_1622e52a40e__8000_00000002.tmp
```

Following are files-

1)jsp file

```
<form action="uploadAction" method="POST" class="basic-form" id="UploadEmpDocument" name="UploadEmpDocument" enctype="multipart/form-data">                 
                    <div class="title-bar">
                        <h4>Upload Documents</h4>                       
                    </div>
                    <div class="inner">

                        <div class="row">



                            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">

                                <label>Select File:</label>
                                <input type="file" name="uploadFile" id="fileToUpload">
                                <button type="button" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-success">Upload</button> 
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </form>
```

2)Struts.xml

```
<!-- File Upload -->
        <action name="UploadDocForm">
             <interceptor-ref name="authStack"></interceptor-ref> <!-- authStack, defaultStack -->
            <result name="error">view/common/error.jsp</result>
            <result name="success">view/employees/UploadDocuments.jsp</result>
        </action>

        <action name="uploadAction" class="com.zCon.controller.FileUploadAction" method="execute">
            <interceptor-ref name="fileUpload">  <!-- authStack,fileUpload -->
                <param name="maximumSize">2097152</param> <!-- 2GB? --> 
                <param name="allowedTypes">  
                    image/png, image/gif, image/jpg, image/jpeg, image/pjpeg, image/pdf, text/plain
                </param>  
            </interceptor-ref>  
            <!-- <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"></interceptor-ref> -->
            <result name="input">view/employees/UploadDocuments.jsp</result>  <!-- UserImage.jsp -->
            <result name="success">view/employees/success.jsp</result>  <!-- view/employees/UploadDocuments.jsp -->
        </action>
        <!-- File Upload -->
```

3)web.xml

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>Portal</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>

    <filter-class>
        org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter
        <!-- org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher -->
    </filter-class>

  </filter>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: That was not the issue earlier.Now my that problem is solved ,i have updated by question with new problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please use

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

in jsp frorm

Comment: I have used it already.

Comment: Please share jsp code also.

Comment: jsp code added to question,please check

Comment: If you are using struts version 2.3 and greater, add <constant name="struts.multipart.enabled" value="true"/> and <constant name="struts.multipart.maxSize" value="2097152" /> in your struts.xml file

Comment: on which web server you are running this application. For tomcat, you have to update postsize for 2gb.

Answer (score 0):

it it's an method

use `onsubmit="return uploadAction"` instead of `action="uploadAction"` if you are calling `script method`

---

if it's an url use

use `action="/uploadAction"`.
see `action` contains `/` before `uploadAction`

Comment: done not solved